# Linear accelerometer on a rotating platform

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, physics, gyro

I want to measure the linear speed of a vehicle putting the accelerometer on its wheel. Assume the vehicle is moving at a velocity 70 KMPH and its wheel has a radius (R = Radius) 30 CM. I made this analogy, If the accelerometer will be placed on the wheel at position R/2 whose Z axis is now orthogonal to the wheel and let us assume there is no tilt in X and Y axis.

[image: Image Axis of Sensor]

The Accelerometer reading in X and Y should give the net accelerometer which is a_translational + a_rotational + TIGA = (R/2)*alpha + (R/2)* omega ^2 + TIGA where aplha is the angular accelartion and omega is the angular velocity and TIGA is the Tilt induced gravitational accelarion.

If my above observation is correct, how can i calculate TIGA factor? Will it change with the rotation degrees? How to balance it?

For calculating the speed (to correlate with 70 KMPH) i should integrate the accelration value in that period. In this case? Which accelration value from the accelrometer data should be considered? Should the a_rotational and TIGA factor must be removed from the data before integration?

Comment: Why not just use a MEMS YAW gyro: http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/37-03/gyro.html

Comment: You mean just multiply the gyro output with the radius of the wheel and we get the velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are going to read from your accelerometer:
$$
\begin{align*}
 a_{r}= & \frac{R}{2}\left ( 2\cos\vartheta \: \ddot{\vartheta } - \dot{\vartheta}^{2}\right )& +g \sin \vartheta\\ 
 a_{t}= & \frac{R}{2}\left ( \ddot{\vartheta } - 2\sin\vartheta \: \ddot{\vartheta } \right ) & +g \cos\vartheta
\end{align*}
$$
and you want to get
$$
v=R\dot{\vartheta}
$$
If your speed is high enough (\$v=R\dot{\vartheta }\gg \sqrt{2gR} \approx 8.7km/h\$) you can neglect the other two factors and assume \$v=\sqrt{2a_{r}/R}\$ (this is the case for a normal travel by car).

Anyway the radial component can be easily filtered to obtain just \$\dot{\vartheta }\$, as the frequency of \$\vartheta\$ is way higher than the frequency of \$v\$.

I suggest you to simulate these equations and try to find a good strategy for your needs before going further. The following is a matlab code to simulate an experimental speed profile.

```
v = [20*ones(1,50*1e4) 20*2.^(-(1:(50*1e4))/(50*1e4)) 10+20/(50*1e4)*(1:(50*1e4)) 30*ones(1,50*1e4)];
plot(v)
disp('Velocity 72kph exponentially decreasing to 36kph then linearly increasing to 144kph')
pause

x = cumsum(v)/1e4;
theta = x / R;
xs = x + R/2*cos(theta);
ys = R/2*sin(theta);
xsd = diff(xs)*10000;
xsdd = diff(xsd)*10000;
ysd = diff(ys)*10000;
ysdd = diff(ysd)*10000+9.81;
ar = xsdd .* cos(theta(2:end-1)) + ysdd .* sin(theta(2:end-1));

plot(ar)
disp('Radial acceleration')
pause

plot(R*sqrt(-ar/R*2))
disp('Velocity recovered from radial acceleration')
pause
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you let me know, How did you get to calculate the first part of At in the expression(why are you substracting omega ??). Any reference !!

As the accelerometer now is at rest and its position is at at + Y axis, so there is only one component of accelration which is gravity. hence, i should get A radial = g and a tangential = 0. using the above equation, it is different.

Comment: I would also like to know, how did you assume Theta, with respect to which axis?

Comment: I used your convention of clockwise positive angles (thus inverting the sign of derivatives), going from the x to the y axis in your picture.

Comment: Now, if you assume the Accelerometer at Y axis on my picture and it is at rest, the only acceleration it should get is gravity, at theta = 90, which is in the radial direction and there should be no tangential component(due to no rotation). Why we are not getting g as Ar and 0 as At?

Comment: Regarding filtering i plan to go ahead as mentioned in this reference. [SeeLink](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1350453312001294)

Comment: In the At, should not it be like R/2* alpha + R/2* (omega)^2 + gsin(theta). As i see, you mentioned in the second part (R/2 *(-omega)). where omega is the time derivative of theta.

Comment: I changed accelerations according to the correct english naming convention.

Comment: [Link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5408811&isnumber=5408796). In the following paper, if you refer equation 1 and 2, You will see what i mean. if you  consider (theta')^2 instead of (theta') then i think, it will be correct. Kindly correct me , if i am wrong.

Comment: I had some sign inversion in my equations... now everithing is fine.

Comment: Can you kindly tell, how this, 2cos(theta) and 2 sin(theta) component come?

Comment: I found this equation more correct. can you compare this with your sets of equations, and give feedback [EquationLink](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94830/accelerometer-on-a-wheels-rim/94858#94858?newreg=b835c2270a4147088958e743a99f23ce)

Comment: I simulated my equations and I'm sure they are correct. You can try by yourself by using the code I posted (if you don't have matlab you can try with octave or scilab as I have not used any toolbox function). The coefficients for \$\ddot{\vartheta }\$ arise considering that the origin of the reference frame is moving (\$x_{0}=vt\$) so I assumed the position of the sensor to be \$x_{s}=R/2\cos\vartheta+R\vartheta, y_{s}=R/2\sin\vartheta\$, double differentiate this, project on the normal and tangent axis, and you'll have my equations.

Comment: Yes, then you are absolutely correct. Thank you. On your comment "Anyway the radial component can be easily filtered to obtain just ϑ˙, as the frequency of ϑ is way higher than the frequency of v". we have here  ϑ˙(omega)and also  ϑ˙˙ (alpha) in the equation of radial accelration. How to differenciate between ϑ˙(omega)and also  ϑ˙˙ (alpha) ?

Comment: When you low-pass filter, everything that is multiplied by \$\sin\vartheta\$ or  \$\cos\vartheta\$ is attenuated, so you'll have no \$\ddot{\vartheta}\$ contribute after filtering.

Comment: [Codelink](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9yj8k0xktgqjh0e/matcode.m?dl=0) Can you please tell me in my code how to do filtering here with A_r, as you can see a huge noise in A_r part. Which filter should be used for this verlocity profile? How to get back velocity from A_r using filtering method?

Comment: You forgot the scale factor at lines 3, 12 and 13. The v vector is *sampled* at 10kHz, you must take this into account when you integrate (cumsum) or differentiate (diff). If you still have doubts, please, open another question as it is hard to give responses in comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not a straightforward problem.  The chain rule will bite you where you don't expect it to.  Believe it or not, I'd low pass filter for the centripetal acceleration, use that and the tire circumference to calculate angular rate of the tire, and use that for speed.

Comment: Can you csuggest me about the LPF function? WHich cut off frewuqncy, which sample frequency and which order need to be used for LPF? What should i get after LPF of radial acceleration? If it will be omega, should i just multiply radius to get the speed (as v = radius * omega)

Answer (score 1):

You get a nice component of the acceleration due to the rotation. I would just measure that frequency and the velocity follows directly from the wheel circumference. This has the massive advantage that no calibration of the sensor position and orientation is needed.

To do this, calculate the mean value, subtract it from the signal, and find the zero crossings of the result. The time between successive positive crossings is a good measure of the time for one revolution. You may need to apply a small amount of low pass filtering to ensure you get just one crossing per revolution.

Or do an FFT of the signal and the largest frequency component is what you want (smoothing then comes for free).

Comment: Thank you. In the radial accelration part, if i take the FFT, I will have theta, theta' (omega), theta''(alpha) components. As theta, will have maximum frequency, then omega and then alpha. Do you mean that using a Band Pass Filter we should extract the theta' (Omega).

Comment: Yes I think the most significant and high frequency component will give you $\theta$. This should be very obvious when you look at the FFT .

Comment: I am not familiar with FFT, but it should give me the representation of signal in frequency domain. SO here i would get all the frequency as per the equation. As theta will have higher frequency , passing through LPF, we will get only the component of velocity (that means omega). Now this component multiplied with the radius , would give us the linear velocity. Is this approach correct?

Comment: @Student15 yes that is exactly right. And since your FFT returns an array of (complex) amplitudes sorted by frequency, you could simply take the magnitude and look for the fist big peak starting from the high end. Once you have looked at a couple of spectra it should be obvious to see what processing you would need.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is equal to the rotational velocity multiplied by radius, I suggest using this formula instead for your application, so you just have to do the math instead of using more electronics. So, use the formula: acceleration = (alpha)(radius) + (omega)^2(radius) and solve for omega.

Comment: Yes, but you did not consider the gravity component (TIGA) ! Which will have a significant effect.